# Eclipse - Edit the autofill template in Content Assist

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

I went to Preferences -> Editor -> Templates and I edited the `for loops` so the brackets would begin on the next line instead of the current line. I clicked Apply -> Okay and the changes showed up in the Templates section. But when I use the Content Assist it still autofills the `for loops` so the brackets begin on the current line.

Comment: I wonder if your settings under Java->Code Style->Formatter might be interfering?

Comment: thanks! edited the brackets there and everything is working now